# Excel VBA filter loop

Tags: excel, vba

Any suggestions how to tackle the following problem? I have a list of ~15 different items, out of which only some are present in a table (Excel 2016) at any particular moment.

I want to use VBA in order to loop through the existing table range and **filter** it based on **every distinct Item**. When found, I want to launch additional code.

I don't have a problem with a simple code to look for and filter out one hardcoded item and if found, run another code snippet and if not, quit. However I feel there must be a better option as scheduling 15 different scripts to run is very inefficient and I'd also need to start them one by one.

Any suggestions on how to do this with 1 code, instead of running 15 different ones?

A dummy table is perhaps better explanatory - out of total 15 different items, it currently has 4 different ones. I'd like loop though the table and filter out each Item separately and run the code with each of them.

[image]

This is what I came up with, but this one would only work if duplicated and launched 15 times with different hardcoded filtering criterias:

```
Sub Filter_single ()

Dim Filtered as Range  
Set Filtered = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Apple"

    End With

If Filtered is Nothing Then
End If

... if range "Filtered" is not Nothing, run another code here...

End Sub
```

Comment: Nest your filter loop inside a unique values loop - *agh this will be so easy when `UNIQUE` spill function is available.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest your code inside a unique value loop. I just hard coded the values of `Arr` here, but you can load this in various ways (all of which are well documented on this site)

---

```
Sub Filter_single()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim Filtered As Range, i As Long, Arr

Arr = Array("Apple", "Orange", "Grape")

For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
    With ws.ListObjects("Table1").Range
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Apple"
        Set Filtered = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With

    If Filtered.Rows.Count > 1 And Not Filtered Is Nothing Then
        'Run Macro Here
    End If

    Set Filtered = Nothing
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks promising, will test it out. One follow up though which might be necessary. Is it possible to slow down the loop process in case the nested extra macro is slow or will the new cycle not run anyway unless the nested macro is complete?

Comment: It won’t run until the other finishes

Comment: I think Criteria1:="Apple" is not correct, however swapping to Criteria1:= Arr looked to have worked. 

I have trouble running the extra code - I tried something very basic for test purposes like "Range("A2").Value = Range("A1").Value but other than looping through filters, that one wouldn't run.